# how to split a string by space in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a string like this:
'My name is Jason Fernandez.'

Strings separated by speace have different lengths.
I want to get each of the strings separated by space, which means I want to have 5 different items as a result.

```
1 my
2 name
3 is
4 Jason
5 Fernandez
```

I am using SQL server 2008.

Thank you.

Comment: Google:  "sql server split function"

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @siteIds VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @strngLen int
DECLARE @split TABLE(siteId VARCHAR(100))

SET @siteIds = 'My name is Jason Fernandez'

SET @strngLen = CHARINDEX(' ', @siteIds)

WHILE CHARINDEX(' ', @siteIds) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @strngLen = CHARINDEX(' ', @siteIds);

    INSERT INTO @split
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@siteIds,1,@strngLen - 1);

    SET @siteIds = SUBSTRING(@siteIds, @strngLen + 1, LEN(@siteIds));
END

INSERT INTO @split
SELECT @siteIds

SELECT * FROM @split
```

Comment: Probably the worst way to split a string

Comment: Do you have a better way to get the results? No wonder you are weak af mate.

Comment: Please check the duplicate link.. Its just a suggestion don't take it in bad way.. stay cool

Comment: The right and polite way to say the same thing would be "There is a better way to split the string" Basic English.

Comment: Ok my bad......